# Dynamic Rendering with V-If

Tags: vue.js

I am creating a form and I want to show certain fields only when a certain button is pressed, but take those fields away and show other fields when another button is pressed.

I am new to vue (and coding), but I think I'm wanting to use v-if, but I can't seem to return the values back to the v-if field.

If the type MAGAZINE is selected, then a method sets the typeIsMagazine to TRUE and the other typeselectors to FALSE. I would expect that once typeIsMagazine is set to true, then the v-if would be triggered and the form fields will be shown.

The method is being triggered, and I am testing it with console.log so I know the if functions are working. I just don't think it's being returned to v-if.

```
<template>
<form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
 <label class="main">Type:</label>
 <div class="type-row">
  <div class="sub-column">
    <div
      class="sub"
      @click="updateType('auto_stories')"
      :class="{ selected: type === 'auto_stories' }"
    >
      Book
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-column">
    <div
      class="sub"
      @click="updateType('article')"
      :class="{ selected: type === 'article' }"
    >
      Article
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-column">
    <div
      class="sub"
      @click="updateType('website')"
      :class="{ selected: type === 'website' }"
    >
      Website
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<template v-if="typeIsWebsite">
  <label class="main">Website:</label>
  <input type="text" class="text" v-model="url" required />
</template>
<template v-if="typeIsArticle">
  <label class="main">Magazine:</label>
  <input type="text" class="text" v-model="magazine" required />
</template>

<button class="form">Add Entry</button>
</form>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
data() {
return {
  typeIsWebsite: false,
  typeIsArticle: false,
  typeIsBook: false,
};
},
methods: {

updateType(typeSelect) {
  this.type = typeSelect;
  let typeIsWebsite = false;
  let typeIsBook = false;
  let typeIsArticle = false;

  if (typeSelect === "website") {
    typeIsWebsite = true;
    typeIsArticle = false;
    typeIsBook = false;
  } else if (typeSelect === "article") {
    typeIsWebsite = false;
    typeIsArticle = true;
    typeIsBook = false;
  } else if (typeSelect === "auto_stories") {
    typeIsWebsite = false;
    typeIsArticle = false;
    typeIsBook = true;
  }
  return typeIsWebsite, typeIsArticle, typeIsBook;
 },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `updateType`, your variables `typeIsWebsite`, `typeIsBook`, etc are declared as local variables using let. Thus, when you do the `if`, you are updating local variables, not your component's instance variables.
To fix, remove the `typeIsX` variable declarations in `updateType`, and use `this.typeIsX` to refer to each variable.
Like so:

```
updateType(typeSelect) {
  this.type = typeSelect;

  if (typeSelect === "website") {
    this.typeIsWebsite = true;
    this.typeIsArticle = false;
    this.typeIsBook = false;
  } else if (typeSelect === "article") {
    this.typeIsWebsite = false;
    this.typeIsArticle = true;
    this.typeIsBook = false;
  } else if (typeSelect === "auto_stories") {
    this.typeIsWebsite = false;
    this.typeIsArticle = false;
    this.typeIsBook = true;
  }
 }
```

Finally, the function doesn't need to return anything.

As an extra advice, note that this is really verbose code and at least in your use case you don't need all the flags. Just keeping the current type as a string and then comparing against that would be enough. For example:
`this.typeIsWebsite` is equivalent to `this.type === 'website'`.

Remember: less code means less errors!